# URL mapping mistake in Django

Tags: django

I am creating "Loan Application and Verification System" in which,
This page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/applicant_policy/2/` is rendering information about the applicant who has taken a few policies,
The template is rendering the code given below

```
...
...
{% for policy in orders %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{policy.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{policy.policy_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{policy.bank}}</td>
                    <td>{{policy.Tenure}}</td>
                    <td>{{policy.Processing_Fees}}</td>
                    <td>{{policy.loan_amount}}</td>
                    <td>{{policy.applicant.CIBIL_score}}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{ url 'applying_for_policy' policy.id}">Check</a></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
...
...
```

I have created an anchor tag in the last column which would take the user to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/applying_for_policy/1/
```

instead it takes it to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/applicant_policy/2/%7B%20url%20'applying_for_policy'%20policy.id%20%7D
```

and gives "Page Not Found" error

the urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('adminpage/',views.admin_page, name='adminpage'),
    path('applicant_policy/<str:pk_test>/', views.applicant_policy, name="applicant_policy"),
    path('applying_for_policy/<str:pk>/',views.applying_for_policy, name="applying_for_policy"),
]
```

The view function which is been handling the "applying_for_policy" view

```
def applying_for_policy(request, pk): 
    customer = Policy.objects.get(id=pk)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Thus creating an URL mapping issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url should be

```
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'applying_for_policy' policy.id %}">Check</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the hashtags on   {# url 'applying_for_policy' policy.id #} and change it to   {% url 'applying_for_policy' policy.id %} that should help as Django doesn't use hashtags to map template urls it makes use of the percentage sign(%) to do that this might be the reason for your error

Comment: The syntax "{# url 'applying_for_policy' policy.id #} " was to comment out that particular tag but I get it how it could be confusing, sorry my bad. 
I have edited it out.